# jQuery Cycle Plugin [cycle] terminating; too few slides: 1

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm getting below error:

[cycle] terminating; too few slides: 1

Below is the code for jQuery Cycle. I'm not sure why this is coming out in Chrome

```
var inners = $('ul#output li').cycle().cycle('stop');

        var slideshow = $('ul#output').cycle({
            fx: 'scrollHorz',
            speed: 300,
            timeout: 0,
            startingSlide: 0, 
            before: function() {

                // stop all inner slideshows
                inners.cycle('stop');

                // start the new slide's slideshow
                $(this).cycle({
                    fx: 'fade',
                    timeout: 1000,
                    autostop: true,
                    end: function() {
                        // when inner slideshow ends, advance the outer slideshow
                        slideshow.cycle('next');
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $.featureList(
                $("#tabs li a"),
                $("#output li"), {
                    start_item  :   0
                }
            );
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

actually this error comes when your sliding elements Less than 2.
if you want to run cycle plugin in single element also then 
go to

> jquery.cycle.all.js

and find

```
if (els.length < 2) {
            log('terminating; too few slides: ' + els.length);
            return;
        }
```

and change the condition limit to 1 like

```
if (els.length < 1) {
            log('terminating; too few slides: ' + els.length);
            return;
        }
```

if you don't want run single element then you should put condition on your language side
that render element if elements count > 2

Cheers!

Mudassar Ali

Answer (score 1):

It is something with your first line:

```
var inners = $('ul#output li').cycle().cycle('stop');
```

You are trying to create `.cicle()` inside a `.cicle()`. If you try:

```
var inners = $('ul#output').cycle().cycle('stop');
```

It doesn't return any error.